# retrieve mysql result to jquery

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is that I can't retrieve the result of the mysql result via ajax, please help

ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "do_find_courses.php",
    //data:{question_id:question_id,answer:answer},
    data:{user_id:user_id}, dataType:'json',
    success:function(msg) {
        alert ('asdasd')
        // $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
        // $('#result').show();
        $('p').html(msg);
    }
 });
```

PHP code:

```
 $final=array();
 $sql_courses=mysql_query("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM course") or die (mysql_error());
 $row_courses = mysql_fetch_array($sql_courses);            
 $result=$row_courses['course_name'];
 //array_push($final,$result);
 //print_r($result);
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: why are you sending user_id when you are not using it, and does it have any value in it?

Comment: What does `alert(msg);` show? Also you are not using `user_id` anywhere in your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Change PHP Code as below

```
$final = array();
$sql_courses = mysql_query("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM course") or die(mysql_error());
$row_courses = mysql_fetch_array($sql_courses);

echo json_encode($row_courses);
```

change php code as below:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "do_find_courses.php",
     //data:{question_id:question_id,answer:answer},
     data: {
         user_id: user_id
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (msg) {
         $('p').html(msg.course_name);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to send it with a key value like this:

> And its better to use `console.log(variable);` to check variable's content

ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "do_find_courses.php",
    //data:{question_id:question_id,answer:answer},
    data:{user_id:user_id}, dataType:'json',
    success:function(msg) {
        alert ('asdasd');
                    console.log(msg);//You should check output of this in browser console
        // $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
        // $('#result').show();
        $('p').html(msg.cname);
    }
 });
```

PHP code:

```
 $final=array();
 $sql_courses=mysql_query("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM course") or die (mysql_error());
 $row_courses = mysql_fetch_array($sql_courses);            
 $result=$row_courses['course_name']; // this will have first_coures_name (an string)
 $final['cname']=$result;
 //print_r($result);
 echo json_encode($final); //the output should be this {'cname':'first_course_name'}
```

Comment: @user1657720 you should accept the answer you prefer. You should click on check mark on left side of the answer you want to accept.